# Deleting Large Table IN Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

I try to delete a table that has 10.000.000 records inside.

Code:

```
      executors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mDatabase.repo().deleteTable();
       });
```

But it takes so long and for some reason it increases internal storage and then i get the following message ***"Cannot rollback: no transaction is active"*** and emulator says low space disk.

Any ideas why this happens?